# How to list all subdirectories in a given directory in C?

Tags: c, linux, list, directory, subdirectory

Is there a way to list all subdirectories in a given directory path in C? I was hoping I would be able to do it with the `stat()` function but it only works on files.

Comment: Richie: `stat()` should tell at least that it's a UNIXoid OS.

Comment: You are correct that `stat()` works on files, but directory entries are also files.  So `stat("/etc/passwd", &buf)` and `stat("/etc/", &buf)` will both work.

Comment: The Operating System is Linux.

Comment: My overall goal is to use threads to find the size of a given directory and sub-directories. I am trying to approach this by finding how many sub-directories are in the given directory and then creating that amount of threads.

Comment: This isn't really a C question. It's a platform question (Linux, I guess), with "and I'm using C" tacked onto the end.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

stat works on directories too.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int num_dirs(const char* path)
{
    int dir_count = 0;
    struct dirent* dent;
    DIR* srcdir = opendir(path);

    if (srcdir == NULL)
    {
        perror("opendir");
        return -1;
    }

    while((dent = readdir(srcdir)) != NULL)
    {
        struct stat st;

        if(strcmp(dent->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(dent->d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;

        if (fstatat(dirfd(srcdir), dent->d_name, &st, 0) < 0)
        {
            perror(dent->d_name);
            continue;
        }

        if (S_ISDIR(st.st_mode)) dir_count++;
    }
    closedir(srcdir);
    return dir_count;
}
```

---

Comment: thanks, i man'd quite a bit of the functions you used to understand what was going on and it works!

Comment: Because this seemed like such a good answer, I've edited it slightly to make it a bit more robust - replacing `stat` with `fstatat` (which means you don't have to muck about creating the full path, and also avoid race conditions), and handling errors from `opendir` and `fstatat` (which are reasonably likely in practice - things like "permission denied").

Comment: @GuyL your edit was unfortunately rejected.  I don't know a lot of straight UNIX api stuff, but it might be easier to be approved if you add the correct includes so it's easy to verify that it compiles.

Answer (score 5):

You want [readdir(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/readdir).

Answer (score 3):

```
/*
I had need in something like this not so long ago (my difference is I
needed recursive scan) so I added only some comments... Sorry for recursion
but I was short of time and this was only part of internal one-time tool.
*/

/* Print all the dirs starting from <path> [maybe recursive]. */
int print_dirs(const char *path, int recursive)
{
    struct dirent *direntp = NULL;
    DIR *dirp = NULL;
    size_t path_len;

    /* Check input parameters. */
    if (!path)
        return -1;
    path_len = strlen(path);  

    if (!path || !path_len || (path_len > _POSIX_PATH_MAX))
        return -1;

    /* Open directory */
    dirp = opendir(path);
    if (dirp == NULL)
        return -1;

    while ((direntp = readdir(dirp)) != NULL)
    {
        /* For every directory entry... */
        struct stat fstat;
        char full_name[_POSIX_PATH_MAX + 1];

        /* Calculate full name, check we are in file length limts */
        if ((path_len + strlen(direntp->d_name) + 1) > _POSIX_PATH_MAX)
            continue;

        strcpy(full_name, path);
        if (full_name[path_len - 1] != '/')
            strcat(full_name, "/");
        strcat(full_name, direntp->d_name);

        /* Ignore special directories. */
        if ((strcmp(direntp->d_name, ".") == 0) ||
            (strcmp(direntp->d_name, "..") == 0))
            continue;

        /* Print only if it is really directory. */
        if (stat(full_name, &fstat) < 0)
            continue;
        if (S_ISDIR(fstat.st_mode))
        {
            printf("%s\n", full_name);
            if (recursive)
                print_dirs(full_name, 1);
        }
    }

    /* Finalize resources. */
    (void)closedir(dirp);
    return 0;
}

/* We are taking first argument as initial path name. */
int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
        return -1;

    print_dirs(argv[1], 1);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, `stat(2)` works fine on files and devices of all types.  It reads through symbolic links to the file at the far end; if you need the information about the symbolic link itself, use `lstat(2)`.

To list the names of all directories within a single directory (non-recursively), use a combination of the `readdir(3)` family of functions.

To list the names of all directories recursively, use the `ftw(3)` or `nftw(3)` functions to do a 'file tree walk' (from whence cometh their names; 'n' is for 'new').