# how to show detailed file information under a directory in Linux Terminal? - C++

Tags: c++, linux, command-line

So this program supposed to print all of the file information under a directory. Below is my c++ code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <sys/types.h>

    using namespace std;

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        execvp("/bin/ls",&argv[0]);
fork(); // should I put it here?
        perror("failed to execute the command");
        cout<< "The PID is " << getpid() <<endl;    
        return 0;
    }
```

I think the command is supposed to be `ls -a` but how do I implement it in the program? Currently it only prints all of the files, not the information of each file.

Also how do I print the PID? Because the `getpid()` function doesn't seem to work.

Thank you!

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723002/how-to-list-all-subdirectories-in-a-given-directory-in-c.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a long listing of files, the command is `ls -l`. To include hidden files as well (those that start with a `.`), the command is `ls -a`. These of course can be combined into `ls -la` which will give a long listing of all files in the given directory.

Also, with the code you have, lines of code after the `execvp` call will never run. When you call an `exec` function, it replaces the current running program with whatever you are calling via `exec`. If you put the `cout` line before your call to `execvp` you should see the expected output. If you wanted to print those lines after calling `execvp`, you would need to use `fork`, which essentially creates a copy of your program as a child of the original program. [This](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fork.html) should give you some good resources about fork if that's the type of functionality you're hoping to achieve.

To properly call fork in C, your code will look something like this:

```
pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid == -1) //if there was an error
    ...
else if(pid > 0) //if child who resulted from the fork
    ...
else //if the parent who called the fork
    ...
```

I'm not exactly sure of your intention, so I'll let you fill in the code, but that's the general sense of using fork.

To pass arguments to your `execvp` call, you give it an array of strings which you are already doing in your code. You are passing all arguments to the `execvp` call, so after compiling, running `./a.out -la` should pass `-la` giving you an `exec` call to `ls -la`.

Comment: I added forking but was I doing it right? Also how do you execute the ls -a or ls -la command in C++? Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer to answer your questions. For a better sense of using `execvp` and giving arguments to it (like `-la`), check out this [page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/exec.html) for detailed information on using the `exec` family of functions.