# C++ open folder and fetch for subfolder

Tags: c++, windows

I'm finding a way to fetch all the subfolders in a known folder, and open them, then keep finding all the subfolders in that folder, keep opening them until there aren't any subfolders left more, then move to another folder in C++. Thanks for help!

Comment: IMHO, this is too broad for a SO question. If your environment support C++17 or above, you can use the [`std::filesystem`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) library. Else you can find it in boost. If neither is an option, you will have to use OS specific calls.

Comment: Thanks for helpful tips are are welcome,  but don't forget to accept and/or upvote the answer. It took someone's time and effort to write it for you, just for free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on Serge Ballesta's comment.

If you can compile c++17, then make use of std::filesystem.

- This [SO provides a solution to 'LS' a specific dir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/612176/7484918). Need to add recursion.

However, if you are not able to run c++17, then you need to consider the OS you are working on.

If Linux and using GCC, use native "dirent.h"

- [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1723583/7484918) post with solution.
- Just need to #include dirent.h

If Windows, can use either windows.h or use a popular libarary extension of dirent.h for windows.

- If using windows.h native methods, here is a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6139423/7484918) with solution.
- If using windows extended dirent.h. Here is the github [link](https://github.com/tronkko/dirent). Just need to grab the header and add to your project.

  - Can be nicer if working cross platform
  - I just used this on my project, and was very convenient and easy.

Comment: Nice! I think I will try dirent.h